# Cannot get PHPSHIELD installed

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php

I have a x64 virtual machine running the latest Plesk on PHP Version 5.6.15.

I'm trying to install Phpmotion and it is giving me this message:

[image]

I tried the following step, after various other tries:

```
Download phpshield from http://phpshield.com/loaders/phpshield.loaders.linux.zip

After download unzip and upload the file phpshield.5.2.lin in to /usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs folder

Now you need to edit the php.ini file using the following command
sudo nano / etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

add the following line at the end of the file

extension=phpshield.5.2.lin

Save and exit the file

Now you need to restart apache server using the following command
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I checked the phpinfo and it shows the following:

```
extension_dir: /opt/plesk/php/5.6/lib/php/modules 
^^^ which is where I put the phpshield.5.2.lin file
Loaded Configuration File: /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.ini
^^ the ini that I edited to add the extension
```

I restarted apache and I even restarted the virtual machine and I cannot get past this part.

Anyone have any suggestions?